# Retrieving YouTube Channel Uploads in Objective-C using v3 of the API

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api

**Hello, I'm trying to fetch channel object from the youtube api using the google-api library in xcode, this is the code I'm using:**

```
    //youtubeService type is GTLServiceYouTube
    youtubeService = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
    youtubeService.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
    //auth is the object from the authentication callback 
    youtubeService.authorizer = auth;
    videoQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube 
    queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"RayWilliamJohnson"];
    videoQuery.maxResults = 20;

    youtubeTicket = [youtubeService executeQuery:videoQuery completionHandler:
^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id channel, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@" %@ ", error.description);
                NSLog(@"WIN! : %@ ", channel);
                }];
```

**So far I've been getting this error:**

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=-32602 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (RayWilliamJohnson)"
>   UserInfo=0x7532c40 {error=RayWilliamJohnson,
>   GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7533d30:
>   {message:"RayWilliamJohnson" code:-32602 data:[1]},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(RayWilliamJohnson)}

**Any idea what is throwing this error?**

**Thanks in advance for the help!**

**Edit**:
I've read the documentation in the classes which simply 'does not exist' :P and checked the other examples that also follows the same approach.

**Edit2**: ok I've tried the following changes and none of them worked :(, it worked for me using the same example on the query explorer.

```
videoQuery.maxResults = 20;
videoQuery.q = @"RayWilliamJohnson";
videoQuery.type = @"channel";

/*tried setting the part without calling the query 
 method on GTLQueryYoutube but that did not work videoQuery.part = @"id";*/

videoQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"id"];
//fetching only 20 items.
youtubeTicket = [youtubeService executeQuery:videoQuery completionHandler:
^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id channel, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@" %@ ", error.description);
    NSLog(@"WIN! : %@ ", channel);
    }];
```

the error is slightly different, its saying that I havent specified any filters even though I did.

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=-32602 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (No filter selected.)" UserInfo=0x8870250 {error=No filter selected., GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x88707f0: {message:"No filter selected." code:-32602 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(No filter selected.)}
```

**Edit3**:
ok I've changed couple of things, first I was making a stupid mistake where I was initializing my query after setting parameters which simply removes them. so the code now looks like this:

```
        youtubeService.authorizer = auth;
        videoQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"id"];
        videoQuery.maxResults = 1;
        videoQuery.q = @"RayWilliamJohnson";
        videoQuery.type = @"channel";


        youtubeTicket = [youtubeService executeQuery:videoQuery
                         completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeChannel *channel,
                                             NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@" %@ ", error.description);
            NSLog(@"WIN! : %@ ", channel.description);
            }];
```

but I'm still getting the error of '**no filters specified**' which means that variables are not set either way...

**Edit4**: ok after so many blonde moments I managed to do this, it was the query object I was initializing, I was trying to use the prefixed one that is specifically made for channel lookups where I'm supposed to just use the *queryForSearchListWithPart*, so the code that worked looks like this:

```
youtubeService.authorizer = auth;       
videoQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id"];
videoQuery.maxResults = 1;
videoQuery.q = @"RayWilliamJohnson";      
youtubeTicket = [youtubeService executeQuery:videoQuery
         completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeChannel *channel,
            NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@" %@ ", error.description);
            NSLog(@"WIN! : %@ ", channel.description);
            }];
```

and provided this result:

> 2012-12-12 00:17:21.315 Test[13099:c07]  (null)  2012-12-12
>   00:17:21.316 Test[13099:c07] WIN! : GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse
>   0x727f6d0: {pageInfo:{totalResults,resultsPerPage}
>   etag:""bm4JOKyioI0quSqrxEnI8H7snE4/A2tE7ag9HxUC5HxeD2vDlGNg5iM""
>   nextPageToken:"CAEQAA" kind:"youtube#searchListResponse" items:[1]}

Thanks for your help Jeff

Comment: Glad to hear you have things working now! We really do need to get some "official" Objective-C sample code out there.

Comment: There's an Objective-C sample for YouTube in the library repository now: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample/YouTubeSampleWindowController.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an Objective-C programmer, so I can't specifically advise on how to modify your code, but here's the general issue.

It looks like you're calling the YouTube Data API v3 `channels.list()` method, which is documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

The one required parameter is `part`, and I assume that's what the `ueryForChannelsListWithPart()` method takes in as its one parameter. `part` should be set to something like `id` or `id,contentDetails`, as explained in the docs.

You then need to add in an additional parameter to tell the API which channel you're trying to retrieve information about. The various options are listed in the "Filters" section of the docs.

v3 of the API doesn't support specifying legacy YouTube usernames in a `channels.list()` call. It does take in a `id` parameter, which corresponds to the YouTube channel id(s) of the channel(s) you want to retrieve information about. These are usually of the form `UC...`, and in the case of `RayWilliamJohnson` the channel id is `UCGt7X90Au6BV8rf49BiM6Dg`. (You can figure this out via a `search.list()` call; here's an [example using the API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id&maxResults=1&q=RayWilliamJohnson&type=channel&_h=1&).)

Please note that the channels.list() method doesn't actually return a list of videos. If you want to retrieve the most recent videos in a given channel, you need to make a `channels.list()` call to obtain the corresponding uploads playlist id from the `contentDetails` part, and then make a `playlistItems.list()` call to get the videos in that uploads playlist. We have an example of doing this in [Python](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#my_uploads), but no end-to-end example in Objective-C yet.

Comment: i'll give this a try now and update the thread if I reach any success

Comment: I've tried setting the parameters as you stated but that did not work for me, I'm getting the same error code which is '-32602'

Answer (score 2):

```
service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
service.retryEnabled = YES;
service.APIKey = @"xxxxxxxx";

GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
query.maxResults = 15;
query.q = YOUR_SEARCH_TEXT;
query.fields = @"items(id,snippet)";
query.order = @"viewCount";

[service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *videoInfo in object) {
            [youtubeList addObject:videoInfo.JSON];
        }
        NSLog(@"youtubeList count %lu",(unsigned long)youtubeList.count);
        NSLog(@"youtubeList %@",youtubeList);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
    -- i'm test this currently for pagination --
    GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *playlistItems = object;
    NSLog(@"playlistItems.nextPageToken %@",playlistItems.nextPageToken);
    NSLog(@"playlistItems.prevPageToken %@",playlistItems.prevPageToken);
    if(playlistItems.nextPageToken) {
        NSLog(@"new page!!!");
        query.pageToken = playlistItems.nextPageToken;
        [self requestYoutubeVideo:withText];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No more pages");
    }
}];
```

`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have moved on to Swift now 

Answer (score 1):

Anyone searching on how to find channels by id, use this

```
GTLServiceYouTube *youTubeService = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
youTubeService.APIKey = @"<YOUR_API_KEY>";

GTLQueryYouTube *channelsQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"id,snippet,brandingSettings,contentDetails,invideoPromotion,statistics,status,topicDetails"];
channelsQuery.identifier = @"<CHANNEL_ID>";

[youTubeService executeQuery:channelsQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeChannelListResponse *channelListResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        if (channelListResponse.items.count > 0) {
            GTLYouTubeChannel *channel = channelListResponse.items.firstObject;
            NSLog(@"Got youtube channel - %@", channel);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Cannot find channels with id %@", channelsQuery.identifier);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cannot get youtube channels - %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: I'm so glad I don't have to use ObjC any more thanks for your answer though <3

Comment: Also can be used to retrieve user's channels - just replace "channelsQuery.identifier = @"<CHANNEL_ID>";" with "channelsQuery.mine = YES;"

Comment: Hi @PulKit Goyal, I try the same with you but I got error "No filter selected". Do you know why